# Does optimal solution for a pseudo packing form will be always a convex set?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is the optimal solution for a linear program which is in pseudo-packing forms a convex set?

`pseudo-packing form`
$$\max c^Tx$$
$$ Ax \le b$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Suppose $x_1$ and $x_2$ are optimal solutions, let $\lambda \in (0,1)$,

- check that $\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2$ is feasible.
- compute $c^T(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2)$, express it in terms of $c^Tx_1$.

Comment: can you explain on the second point, please?

Comment: We are trying to show that optimal solution is convex, hence you have to verify that any convex combination of optimal solution is another optimal solution.

Comment: so if $$\lambda=1$$ will get optimal solution right ?

Comment: $\lambda=1$ gives us $x_1$, we want to show that it works for arbitrary $\lambda$.

Comment: what if we have only one optimal solution?

Comment: A singleton point is convex.